# How to call out names automatically?

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, apache2, text-to-speech

I wanted to implement an automatic calling machine using Raspberry Pi 3, which pronounces the things I send to it via a web form.

I turned my Raspberry into a web server using Apache2 and had the following code in its `/var/www/html`. I am using [google_speech 1.0.15](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google_speech/) TTS.

**PHP**

```
<?php
 if($_POST){
      $name=$_POST['name']
      shell_exec("/var/www/html/call.sh $name")
 }
 <html>
 <body>
       <form action="" method="post">
       Name<input type="text" value="name">
       <input type="submit" name="submit">
       </form>
 <\body>
 <\html>
```

**call.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
google_speech -l en "Hello $1"
echo "call.sh executed"
```

I have my audio system connected to the Pi. The script gets executed, as the last echo statement get printed but the speech output is not coming out of the Pi. I believe the line `google_speech -l en "Hello $1"` is not getting executed. The script works fine when executed over terminal. What should I do? Is there any better way of implementing the same?

Comment: It's better if you do `if($_POST['name'])`

Comment: Does this work for you?

Comment: @yivi `if($_POST['name'])` doesn't make `google_speech -l en "Hello $1"` work either

Answer (score 1):

Your  tag doesn't have a "name" defined, so it's not being sent:

It is:

```
Name<input type="text" value="name">
```

And should be:

```
Name <input type="text" name="name">
```

Your code has some glaring security problems, but those lay beyond the scope of your question. I assume you are going to be the sole user for that application hosted on your Pi.

Comment: its my bad that i wrote it as value but the original program has it as name itself, the name is well received by the script and i tried printing also, it works fine but still the line `google_speech -l en "Hello $1"`is not executed . Also please brief on the security problems that you see in the code.